# Unity3d C# Trying to access array in script but in void

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, game-engine

I have been trying to solve this problem for many hours now, but i just cant figure it out.

I need to access the array "letters in the voids "nextItem" and "prevItem", but i get an error saying "ArgumentException: GetComponent requires that the requested component 'GameObject[]' derives from MonoBehaviour or Component or is an interface."

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class buttons_abc : MonoBehaviour {
public int id;
public GameObject[] letters;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    id = 0;
    GameObject[] letters = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("letter");
    letters[id].SetActive (true);
    for (int i = 1; i < 32; i++) {
        letters[i].SetActive (false);
    }

}
public void nextItem(){
    letters = GetComponent<GameObject[]>();
    Debug.Log (id);
    if(id < 32){
        letters[id].SetActive (false);
        letters[id + 1].SetActive (true);
        id++;
    } else {
        Debug.Log("viimane t2ht");
    }
}
public void prevItem(){
    letters = GetComponent<GameObject[]>();
    Debug.Log (id);
        if(id > 0){

            letters[id].SetActive(false);
            letters[id-1].SetActive(true);
            id--;
        } else{
            Debug.Log("esimene t2ht");
        }
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few errors in your script.
1. There's no [GetComponent](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) that can return a [GameObject](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) EVER. Period. The GetComponent function is used to get a SINGLE component attached to a GameObject.
2. That being said, GetComponent cannot return Arrays either. The type you're looking for `GetComponent<GameObject[]>` is invalid. Valid GetComponents calls look like this

```
GetComponent<AudioSource>();
```

3. You have a global array of GameObjects called `letters`. You're then creating ANOTHER array in Start, this time locally, calling it the same thing (`letters`).

Putting it all together

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class buttons_abc : MonoBehaviour {
public int id;
public GameObject[] letters;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    id = 0;
    //Already declared letters globally. Creating another one here locally will mean that your global array will not be populated
    //GameObject[] letters = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("letter");
    letters = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("letter");
    letters[id].SetActive (true);
    for (int i = 1; i < 32; i++) {
        letters[i].SetActive (false);
    }

}
public void nextItem(){
    //GetComponent only works on Components. GameObjects are NEVER components
    //GetComponent cannot return an array
    //letters = GetComponent<GameObject[]>();
    Debug.Log (id);
    if(id < 32){
        letters[id].SetActive (false);
        letters[id + 1].SetActive (true);
        id++;
    } else {
        Debug.Log("viimane t2ht");
    }
}
public void prevItem(){
    //See comment from nextItem()
    //letters = GetComponent<GameObject[]>();
    Debug.Log (id);
        if(id > 0){

            letters[id].SetActive(false);
            letters[id-1].SetActive(true);
            id--;
        } else{
            Debug.Log("esimene t2ht");
        }
} }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, if i hadn't double declared it in the first place, i wouldn't had any problems. I started messing with the getComponent after the first error. But it is fixed now, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Too many wrong things in your code.

1. Declaring GameObject named `letters` then re-declaring it in the `Start()` function again.
2. `letters = GetComponent<GameObject[]>();` Overwriting the current GameObject reference?
3. `GetComponent<GameObject[]>();` You can't do this.(Your main error)
  4.

`for (int i = 1; i < 32; i++) {
        letters[i].SetActive (false);
}`

You have no way to check if your array is out of bound. `i< 32` should be `letters.Length`